# Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got ";" at [20:46] on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to hash values from email column and insert them into salt column
I am fairly new at BigQuery and quite unfamiliar with syntax. I am taking s as email string input and converting it into hash value which will be returned as a string.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION SaltforEmail(s STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS """


                var hash = 0; 

                if (s.length == 0) return hash; 

                for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { 
                    char = s.charCodeAt(i); 
                    hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + char; 
                    hash |=  0; 
                } 

                return toString(hash); 

""";
with s as (SELECT Email as everyone 
FROM `study-in-india-272211.Hashing.Mapping`);
INSERT `study-in-india-272211.Hashing.Mapping` (salt)
VALUES (SaltforEmail(s));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firsty, I didn't understand what you want to do in hash function, but it doesn't return a string. That's why, I changed the function to return just the hash integer. You might want to check the function itself.

Secondly, what you want is updating the table not updating. So, you can use that query:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION SaltforEmail(s STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var hash = 0; 
  if (s.length == 0) return hash; 
  for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { 
    char = s.charCodeAt(i); 
    hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + char; 
    hash |=  0; 
  } 
  return hash; 
""";

UPDATE `study-in-india-272211.Hashing.Mapping`
set salt = SaltforEmail(Email)
```

Comment: added a WHERE clause after that and changed the if to s!=null. Worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Ffs it was a dumb mistake (facepalm)